# Unable to get camera option in file chooser

Tags: android, file, webview, upload, camera

i want to upload images from camera in webview form and i tried the same code at [this](https://infeeds.com/d/CODEmgks/20475/upload-image-file-gallery-or-camera-webv) page.

It works fine in android marshmallow, but doesn't show the camera option in the file chooser (only gallery and others).

What do I lack?

Thanks in advance :)